# How can I build for cdn with webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack

I created a module like this:

```js
export default () => console.log('hello my_module~!')
```

The settings in the `webpack.config.js` file are as follows:

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  output: {
    // ...
    library: 'hello',
    libraryTarget: 'var'
  }
}
```

And in the html file, the script code is:

```html
<script src="/output_my_module.js"></script>
<script>
  hello.default(); // yea~ It's work!!
</script>
```

But the way I want is as follows:

```js
hello(); // I want use like this.
```

What should I do? I read [webpack's doc](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/) but couldn't find a way. (Maybe I missed it because my English wasn't good...)

Answer (score 2):

You should put [libraryExport](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibraryexport) to your config.

```
  library: 'hello',
  libraryTarget: 'var',
  libraryExport: 'default'
```